# How to responsively get Javascript to validate information from HTML5 form textboxes?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a functional Credit Card validation script for a demo assignment. I am attempting to get JavaScript to react to input as the focus() changes from text box to text box. Once I have the JavaScript reactive then I want to validate that data against specific parameters.

I've tried adding onchange methods directly into the HTML5, but something won't work correctly. I am open to all suggestions, I've spent too long at a stalemate.

HTML

```
<h2>Payment
<img style="visibility: hidden" class="mastercard" 
src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/mastercard.png">
<img style="visibility: hidden" class="visacard" 
src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/visa.png">
<img style="visibility: hidden" class="discovercard" 
src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/discover.png">
<img style="visibility: hidden" class="amexcard" 
src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/amex.png">
</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name-on-card">Name on Card</label>
      <input class="cc_name" type="text" name="card-name" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cc-number">Credit card number</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc_number" name="cc_number" placeholder="" maxlength="16">
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <select class="month_year_select" name="month" id="month">
        <option value="">exp month</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <select class="month_year_select" id="year" name="year">
        <option value="">exp year</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="CVV">
      <label for="cc-cvv">CVV</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-cvv" name="cc-cvv" placeholder="" maxlength="4">
    </div>
      <button type="submit" class="myButton"style = "float:right;">Place Order</button>
  </form>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var creditError="Error with Credit Card information";
  var CWError="Error with CW";

document.getElementbyID("cc-cvv").onchange=function(){function CWcheck()};

document.getElementbyID("cc_number").onchange=function(){function creditCheck()};

document.getElementbyID("cc_name").onchange=function(){function upperFunction()};


function CWcheck()
  {
    if (document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc-cvv"].value.length < 3 ||document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc-cvv"].value.length>=5){
      alert(CWError);
      cdocument.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc-cvv"].value.value=" ";
    }
    else if(document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc-cvv"].value.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/)){
      alert(CWError);
      document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc-cvv"].value=" ";
    }
    else if(document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc-cvv"].value.match(/^[-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/)) { 
      alert(CWError);
      document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc-cvv"].value=" ";
    }
    else 
      break;
  }

function upperFunction() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("cc_name").value.toUpperCase();
  }


function creditCheck() {
  {
    if (document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc_number"].value.length < 15 ||document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc_number"].value.length>16){
      alert(creditError);
      document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc_number"].value=" ";
    }
    else if(document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc_number"].value.match(/^[A-Za-z]+$/)){
      alert(creditError);
      document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc_number"].value=" ";
    }
    else if(document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc_number"].value.match(/^[-+]?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/)) { 
      alert(creditError);
      document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc_number"].value=" ";
    }
    else 
      if(document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc_number"].value.match(/^(?:3[47][0-9]{13})$/)){
        document.getElementsByClassName('amexcard').style.visibility="visable";
        document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc_number"].value=" ";
        }
      else if(document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc_number"].value.match(/^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)$/)){
        document.getElementsByClassName('visacard').style.visibility="visable";
        document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc_number"].value=" ";
        }
      else if(document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc_number"].value.match(/^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{14})$/)){
        document.getElementsByClassName('mastercard').style.visibility="visable";
        document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc_number"].value=" ";
        }
      else if(document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc_number"].value;=.match(/^(?:6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12})$/)){
        document.getElementsByClassName('discovercard').style.visibility="visable";
        document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc_number"].value=" "
        }        
      else {
        alert(creditError)
        this.clear()
        }
  }
```

I would ideal like the text box to validate that when a creditcard number is entered it; it will check nothing outside of numbers were entered, the cadence of the numbers match a card type or reset the field, and display the image that the card is next to the "Payment" header.

The Checksum Validation by Alex works very well, with that portion out of the way I can streamline the image setting. So far my code has been updated to the following

Updated HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="/checkout" class = "LeftCheck" name="LeftCheck" id="LeftCheck">
<h2>Payment
<img style="visibility: hidden" class="mastercard" 
src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/mastercard.png">
<img style="visibility: hidden" class="visacard" 
src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/visa.png">
<img style="visibility: hidden" class="discovercard" 
src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/discover.png">
<img style="visibility: hidden" class="amexcard" 
src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/amex.png">
</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name-on-card">Name on Card</label>
      <input class="cc_name" type="text" name="card-name" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cc-number">Credit card number</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc_number" name="cc_number" placeholder="" maxlength="16">
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <select class="month_year_select" name="month" id="month">
        <option value="">exp month</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="">
      <select class="month_year_select" id="year" name="year">
        <option value="">exp year</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="CVV">
      <label for="cc-cvv">CVV</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-cvv" name="cc-cvv" placeholder="" maxlength="4">
    </div>
      <button type="submit" class="myButton"style = "float:right;">Place Order</button>
  </form>
```

And the updated Issue area of my JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('cc_number').addEventListener('change',pictureCheck);
  function pictureCheck()
  {
    var ccNum = this.value;
    if (ccNum.length = 15)
    {
      document.getElementsById('amexcard').style.display='';
    }
    else if(ccNum.value.match(/^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?)$/))
    {
      document.getElementsById('visacard').style.display='';
    }
    else if(ccNum.value.match(/^(?:5[1-5][0-9]{14})$/))
    {
      document.getElementsById('mastercard').style.display='';
    }
    else (ccNum.value;=.match(/^(?:6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12})$/)) 
    {
      document.getElementsById('discovercard').style.display='';
    }
  }
```

Comment: You are not correctly triggering onchange event in vanilla javascript. `document.getElementsByClassName("cc-cvv").addEventListener("change", CWcheck);`. You are using getElementById but you are using className.

Comment: `document.getElementById("cc-cvv").onchange = CWcheck;` is also possible but not what is in OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript part is all wrong. Let me show how it *should* work.

```js
document.getElementById('cc-cvv').addEventListener('change', CWcheck); //recommended way
document.getElementById('cc_number').onchange = creditCheck; //it is OK too

function CWcheck() { //function name should conventionally start with lower case but isn't big deal
  //"this" is the element which fired the event
  if (!/^\d{3,4}$/.test(this.value)) {
    this.value = '';
    this.focus();
    alert('CVV is 3 or 4 digits');
  }
}

function creditCheck() {
  // hide cc logos
  var ccImgs = document.querySelectorAll('h2 img');
  for (var i = 0, ccImg; ccImg = ccImgs[i]; ++i) {
    ccImg.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
  var ccNum = this.value.replace(/\D/g, ''); //remove all non-digits
  if (ccNum.length < 15 /*15 is amex*/ || ccNum.length > 16) {
    alert('CC number is 15 or 16 digits');
    this.focus();
    return false;
  }
  //implement Luhn algorithm
  var check = ccNum.split('') //get array
    .reverse()
    .map(function(el, index) {
      return el * (index % 2 + 1); //multiply even positions by 2
    })
    .join('') //combine array of strings
    .split('')
    .reduce(function(a, b) { //sum digits
      return a + (b - 0);
    }, 0);
  if (!check || (check % 10)) { //checksum should be none-zero and dividable by 10
    alert('Incorrect checksum of CC');
    this.focus();
    return false;
  }
  //test passed. show card logo
  if (/^5[1-5]/.test(ccNum))
    document.querySelector('h2 img.mastercard').style.visibility = 'visible';
  else if (/^4/.test(ccNum))
    document.querySelector('h2 img.visacard').style.visibility = 'visible';
  else if (ccNum.length == 15 && /^3[47]/.test(ccNum))
    document.querySelector('h2 img.amexcard').style.visibility = 'visible';
  else if (/^6011/.test(ccNum))
    document.querySelector('h2 img.discovercasd').style.visibility = 'visible';
  //and so on
  else {
    alert('CC number doesn\'t match known any CC issuer');
    this.focus();
    return false;
  }

  //test passed. format the string
  this.value = ccNum
    .replace(/^(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d+)$/, '$1 $2 $3 $4');
}
```

```html
<h2>Payment
  <img style="visibility: hidden" class="mastercard" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/mastercard.png">
  <img style="visibility: hidden" class="visacard" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/visa.png">
  <img style="visibility: hidden" class="discovercard" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/discover.png">
  <img style="visibility: hidden" class="amexcard" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/amex.png">
</h2>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name-on-card">Name on Card</label>
  <input class="cc_name" type="text" name="card-name" class="form-control" placeholder="">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="cc-number">Credit card number</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc_number" name="cc_number" placeholder="" maxlength="20">
</div>
<!--<div class="">
  <select class="month_year_select" name="month" id="month">
    <option value="">exp month</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="">
  <select class="month_year_select" id="year" name="year">
    <option value="">exp year</option>
  </select>
</div>-->
<div class="CVV">
  <label for="cc-cvv">CVV</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-cvv" name="cc-cvv" placeholder="" maxlength="4">
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** CC issuer from card number is added.

Comment: Alex, I certainly appreciate the effort and code here. While I will eventually include a checksum into this system. I am trying to first start with an IIN validation based off the four main credit card companies, this would test the first Integer and cause one of the images to change their styling to become visible

Comment: It is a little tricky but possible. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_card_number

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with JQuery. When you switch between input fields, you could run your validation script.

```
$("#id1, #id2").focus(function() {
  alert("Focus changed.");
  //run validator
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you use `document.forms["LeftCheck"]["cc-cvv"]` to access the fields of the form. Since you did not include your form start tag, I want to make sure that the `name` field of you form is set to `LeftCheck`, rather than the ID, since I have had this problem before.

You also use `document.getElementbyID()` to access the elements that you are applying the `onchange` listener to. The method is actually `document.getElementbyId()`, with the last letter not capitalized. This may be the reason your events are not firing.

The way that you attach your events to the select element is also incorrect. You can simply do this:

```
document.getElementbyID("cc-cvv").onchange = CWcheck;
```

or alternatively

```
document.getElementbyID("cc-cvv").onchange = function() { CWcheck();};
```

One last thing is that you use regex to validate the input of the credit card field. However, you do this by checking if the input matches an invalid pattern and raises an error if it does. Although this could work, it would be much better to check if the input matches a valid pattern, and if it doesn't, raise in error. This makes your validation code more robust and makes sure that you don't have invalid edge cases that may pass your validation.

Answer (score 0):

Use the inline onblur event

```html
<input type="text" onblur="CWcheck()" />
```